Athena CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE from csv file in S3 bucket results in a table with empty values
I have a very simple csv file with just one column, containing 15000 unique customer IDs. The IDs not contain any spaces or special characters, just alphabets and numbers.
I uploaded this csv file to S3 bucket, and ran the following query to create an external table on ATHENA:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (id String)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = "^([^ ]+).*$" )

LOCATION 's3://foldername/athenaQueryResults/id/'

This query runs successful, so I assume the new table is created successfully based on my csv file.
But, when I try running SELECT * FROM ids  it returns a table with 15,000 values - but all empty values.

Here are the things I tried :

Changing the "input.regex" to "^(.+)$" "^([^ ]+).*$"  and "^(?!#)([^ ]+).*" 

Changing the code to the following :
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (id STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = """,
"escapeChar" = "\"
)
LOCATION 's3://foldername/athenaQueryResults/id/';

Deleting the csv file and re uploading it. The csv file looks completely fine when open on my desktop.


But all of these resulted in the same table with 15,001 empty values. From the fact that the number of rows are correctly picked up, I suspect the directory is accessible and the file is read.
What can be possibly causing this issue? Chatting to gpt didn't seem to do the trick and I'm running out of things to try.
Thank you very much in advance!

When you tried your second option, changing to use OpenCSVSerde, did you drop the table first?  Try that but without the WITH SERDEPROPERTIES option

Personally, I find the most successful way to create a table is to run an AWS Glue crawler. Simply point it to the directory with the data and it will create the table and the schema to match.

I removed the (general) ISO  tag since this is a very product specific issue.

Thank you @TimMylott, dropping the table before running new code was what I was missing!
